# Date of birth saving to MYSQL DB with timestamp or date column type

Tags: mysql, database-design, timestamp, date-format, datetime

i am using MYSQL database and would like to know which of this is a good practice.

way 1 - use column type in DB as timestamp. i.e will contain values like 2012-11-13 00:00:00 way 2 - use column as Date. i.e will contain values like 2012-11-13 in the database.

The question here is, to Store DOB. do we really need timestamp as the column type ? also the time section (00:00:00) is not required for a DOB in my opinion.

Please let me know the correct way to store DOB in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just use `Date` as datatype to store Date field.

Additionally, Specify `Timestamp` over `Datetime` datatype if records are often updated every time the record is changed. If you want to store a specific value you should use a `Datetime` as datatype.

Comment: Correct answer, for the wrong reasons... that's an oversimplification of the appropriate application of timestamp vs datetime, since timestamp is completely appropriate for static values if they will be in-range and you want the native time zone support to convert them.  In this specific case, the fact that timestamp can only hold values between 1970 and 2038 (unlikely to be suitable for DOB) and stores/displays values converted to/from the session time zone and UTC (leading to the wrong date being returned if the time zone changes) would be the relevant pieces of info.